# How long to steam fish for?

Tags: fish, cooking-time, steaming

I bought a Homemaker Food Steamer. How do I steam Fish (Ling Fillet) in it? How long should I steam the fish for?

Comment: I'd read the instruction booklet or google it.  The instruction manual here says 15 minutes: http://www.taylorusa.com/media/IBs/AS1510BL_ib.pdf

Answer (score 2):

When I steam fish, I usually steam it whole, but here are the steps I used to check for done ness

**Are the eyes of the fish white?**  A cooked fish's eyes will harden into white balls as the proteins in the eye coagulate

**Can you separate the fish meat from the bone easily?** Cooked fish should just barely stick to the bone and should come off very easily

**Is the flesh easily separated?** Using a chopstick or some other implement, the fish should "flake"; you should be able to easily separate the "sections" you see in the fish without much force

**Is the flesh a solid colour or translucent?** Cooked fish should be a solid white/pink/whatever colour and not slightly translucent like it is when uncooked

Of course, only the last 2 steps will probably apply to your fillet, but hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @Daniel, thank you for this answer! We ended up just "winging it" and I'm not dead or anything so I think we cooked it right but this answer is really helpful, now I know we're not gonna die lol